# React native Android build failing using 'gradlew assembleRelease'

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, gradle

My app works perfectly in Genymotion emulator.
But I am facing in building app-release.apk.

```
React native version: 0.46.x
```

And build.gradle file:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    ...
```

Also when I use `gradlew assembleDebug`, it succeed with follow output, but generated wrong apk in `app\build\outputs\apk\debug` (not current working version in emulator, but still old version in previous development step.)

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 57s
225 actionable tasks: 216 executed, 9 up-to-date
```

Even when I try to use `gradlew assembleRelease`, it failed with follow output.

```
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process <Android Sdk Folder>\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I <Android Sdk Folder>\platforms\android-24\android.jar -M \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S <My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\generated\source\r\release -F <My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\res\release\resources-release.ap_ -G \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\release\aapt_rules.txt --custom-package com.beostore -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release --no-version-vectors}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process <Android Sdk Folder>\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I <Android Sdk Folder>\platforms\android-24\android.jar -M \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S <My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\generated\source\r\release -F <My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\res\release\resources-release.ap_ -G \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\release\aapt_rules.txt --custom-package com.beostore -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release --no-version-vectors}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1237)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '<Android Sdk Folder>\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:380)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
        ... 9 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 6s
105 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 102 up-to-date
```

Android build-tools versions installed:

```
 23.0.1
 24.0.3
 25.0.0
 25.0.3
 26.0.1
 26.0.2
 27.0.0
 27.0.1
```

And platform versions installed:

```
 android-21
 android-23
 android-24
 android-25
 android-26
```

I googled much, however, couldn't find the solution.
Hope your great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it finally.
I just added this block below `currentBundleTask`'s `doFirst{...}` block in `react.gradle` file.

```
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}")
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}-v4")
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir)
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

This answer is based on the [AvatarQing's comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787#issuecomment-220565305) in Github.

Thanks for all of your attentions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem. I have looked how is executed the aapt and started the same process with same parameters from the command line - in your case this would be, taken from the log you posted (possibly you must replace the placeholders "Android Sdk Folder" etc. by real values):

```
<Android Sdk Folder>\build-tools\27.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I <Android Sdk Folder>\platforms\android-24\android.jar -M \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S <My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\generated\source\r\release -F <My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\res\release\resources-release.ap_ -G \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\release\aapt_rules.txt --custom-package com.beostore -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\<My Project Folder>\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\release --no-version-vectors
```

Then I got the real error message from aapt process, which has been suppressed - in my case by Idea running the graddle build and bringing similar stacktrace like is yours. 
I my case it turned out my AndroidManifest.xml contains some value, which cannot be understood by the compiler, but it can differ in your case, I guess...